# vb.net retrieve one column value in a list of string

Tags: vb.net, string, csv

I have a csv file and I want to get all values in a column and store in a list of string.

Part of my csv contents are as follows:

Item ID    |  Price      | Arrival Time

14/09-7    |  35.9       | 9/7/2014

14/09-8    |  6.45         | 9/7/2014

14/09-9    |  7.1        | 9/7/2014

14/09-10   |  4.75       | 9/7/2014

14/09-11   |  4          | 9/7/2014

14/09-12   |  6.1        | 9/7/2014

14/09-13   |  5.3        | 9/7/2014

The result I want in the list of string is:

"14/09-7,14/09-8,14/09-9,14/09-10,14/09-11,14/09-12,14/09-13"

I haven't found proper example for it. Any advice on it? I am using vb.net(vs2012).

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the lines you want is start from the second line, you can try this:

```
Public Function GetList(ByVal fileName As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(fileName)
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim list As New List(Of String)

    While (reader.Peek() <> -1)
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If index > 0 Then
            Try
                list.Add(line.Split("\\|")(0))
            Catch ex As Exception
                'exception handler
            End Try
        End If
        index += 1
    End While
    Return list
End Function
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `list.Add(line.Split("|")(0).Trim())` ? (well, to make sure, but `list.Add(line.Split(" ")(0))` works aswell, and faster of course :) )

Comment: Thanks all, Sorry I have not enough score to upvote. It works but when I tried to log the list value, I cannot get the expected list of string (logger.info(list)), I guess it is the way I log is not correct(the logged list value is: System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]), could you please advice how to log the "list", thank you very much!

Comment: @littleleaf what do you mean by _"how to log the list.."_? do you want to print the value?

Comment: @littleleaf try `String.Join(",", list.ToArray())`

Comment: Thanks a lot TheQuickBrownFox, it is great! :)